# ActiveMQ "Scheduler" Daemon Threads not terminating

Tags: java, message-queue, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.5 with an embedded broker.  All messages are non persistent.  Producer and Consumer both run within same JVM.
Advisory Support is disabled.

Everything is working fine.  My question is about these "Scheduler" threads running as daemon threads and why they are not 
terminated.

I ran a test where I created about 10 consumers (no producers started) and closed them.  I've confirmed that 
my consumers close successfully, by using advisory support etc...

So inspite of the consumers closing successfully, I see that there's a scheduler Daemon thread created for each consumer, 
and its not terminated, even if I wait for a long time.

Why is that so?  Is there anything I'm not doing?

Here's how my stack stack looked like in Eclipse...there's 10 daemon scheduler threads, each created for a consumer.

```
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQ Broker[MDASJ_BROKER] Scheduler] (Running) 
            Thread [New I/O server boss #1 ([id: 0x008730b8, /0.0.0.0:5555])] (Running) 
            Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQ Task-1] (Running) 
            Daemon Thread [BrokerService[MDASJ_BROKER] Task-1] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQ Task-2] (Running) 
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:1] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:2] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Thread [New I/O server worker #1-1] (Running) 
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQ Task-3] (Running) 
            Thread [New I/O server worker #1-2] (Running) 
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:3] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Thread [New I/O server worker #1-3] (Running) 
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:4] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Thread [pool-4-thread-4] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:5] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:6] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:7] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:8] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:9] Scheduler] (Running)  
            Daemon Thread [ActiveMQConnection[ID:Sprouts-53743-1316899960679-1:10] Scheduler] (Running)
```

Comment: Why do you expect them to terminate? Maybe ActiveMQ is pooling them for future use?

Comment: Thats fair.  Is there a way to control this daemon thread pool count?

Comment: I was just guessing. My point was more, "Why do you care?" If ActiveMQ is doing what it's supposed to do, then let it do it. If you're having a problem with the way ActiveMQ is behaving with regard to messaging, then ask a question about that.

Comment: I care because, if its going to create 1 thread per consumer, then that's not scalable if i have like a 1000 consumers. I want to be able to atleast control the thread pool.

Comment: Then try adding 1000 consumers to see if there's a threading problem, or better yet, 10000. Don't assume you can extrapolate performance of 1000 consumers from 10. Personally, I've run ActiveMQ with up to 500-600 concurrent consumers with no problems, though I never really checked on the thread usage.